# Is there any way to collect failure request(payload) + response data in Jmeter when I execute from command line execution?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

As we are execution our load test from Command line arguments, is there any way to save failed request payload + response data? I have implemented  `Simple Data Writer` **but it doesn't display failed requests payload in generated file also if I check Save as XML it generates file with huge size.**

*Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per JMeter's [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

[image]

If you want to save request and response data:

1. You will **have to go for XML format**
2. The result file will be much larger than the .jtl file in the CSV format.

You can try "implementing" the [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) for failed samplers only, it should reduce your "huge" file size

Example configuration:

[image]

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: it shows everytime when I run multiple times "Append to existing File" or "Overwrite existing File" what could be the solution like it takes new file date/Time wise when I run multipletimes.

Comment: The behaviour is controllable by `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists` [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) which defaults to `ASK`. Other possible choices are `APPEND` and `DELETE`. If you want to append the timestamp - take a look at [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)